# mysql statement can not update add 4 year

Tags: sql, mysql

```
update listweb_copy set expiredate = expiredate + interval 4 year
where expiredate is not null and expiredate < "2001-01-01"
```

I want to add 4 years to expiredate. How can i correct it?

Comment: what version of MySQL are you on?

Answer (score 1):

To add any interval in MySQL, you can use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) or its synonym ADDDATE.
*Check the link for the intervals supported*

The term would be

```
DATE_ADD(expiredate, INTERVAL 4 YEAR)
```

MySQL also states:

> Date arithmetic also can be performed using INTERVAL together with the + or - operator:

```
expiredate + interval 4 year
```

Which is exactly what you had.  Did that not work?

For reference, the part `expiredate is not null` in your query is redundant because for it to succeed in the < test, it cannot be null.  So the whole query would be written

```
update listweb_copy set expiredate = expiredate + interval 4 year
where expiredate < '2001-01-01'
```

or using functions

```
update listweb_copy set expiredate = date_add(expiredate, interval 4 year)
where expiredate < '2001-01-01'
```